# Multiple `maven-jar-plugin` executions causes compilation issue

Tags: java, maven, maven-jar-plugin

I have a multi-module Maven project:

- Project root

  - Module: `main-application`
  - Module: `additional-module` - depends on `main-application`

I'm using `maven-jar-plugin` to compile additional JAR files during when `main-application` is built, based on the contents of some directory:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>additional-jar</id>
            <phase>test-compile</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>test-jar</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <testClassesDirectory>${project.build.directory}/extra-classes-input</testClassesDirectory>
                <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/extra-classes-output</outputDirectory>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

When I `clean test-compile` the project, I get a compilation error in `additional-module`, where it can't find any of the test-scoped classes in `main-application`:

- `package com.main.application` does not exist
- `cannot find symbol` in `additional-module`'s test classes referencing anything from `main-application`'s tests

More specifically, the `testClassesDirectory` property of `maven-jar-plugin` is the inflection point between compilation failing and succeeding:

- When absent, compilation is fine
- When set, compilation fails

I'm trying to compile an *additional* JAR containing code from `extra-classes-input`, but it looks instead I'm *amending* the test classes that `additional-module` is trying to access.

I don't want any of the contents of the extra-JAR on the classpath so I can't add additional modules for the JAR I want to build.

What could I be doing wrong?

Comment: Why do you try to do that? Why not simply making a supplemental module  instead of using configuration etc.. violation of convention over configuration.

Comment: It is often a bad idea to create additional JARs. What are these JARs for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because I was not specifying different `classifier`s, the outputs were overwriting each other - there was a warning I missed to that effect.